# whats best pattern for use entity context object in 3-tier asp.net web form application?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, design-patterns

I have one solution that contains 3 Projects:

1. AutoDataAccess - contains the entity data model
2. AutoBusinessLogic - contains business logic and uses AutoDataAccess
3. AutoPresentation - contains an ASP.NET webforms application

Now I want know what the best pattern is for creating an entity object context in the BusinessLogic layer, e.g. static object, local object, etc. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

BusinessLogic shouldn't know about object context at all! Instantiation of object context should be handled by classes in AutoDataAccess. It's best if You can isolate business logic from database access technology. This is called persistance ignorance (PI).

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to access a `User` object by email address as an example. One way of doing it would be this:

1. Have an `IUserRepository` interface with a `FindByEmailAddress(string email)` method in your `AutoBusinessLogic` project.
2. Have a `UserRepository` object which implements `IUserRepository` in your `AutoDataAccess` project.
3. Have your webforms application inject an instance of `UserRepository` into your page behind the `IUserRepository` interface. There are examples of how to do this [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/DependencyInjection.aspx).
4. When your webforms page calls `IUserRepository.FindUserByEmail`, this goes through into the `UserRepository`. The `UserRepository` then needs an `Entities` object with which to find the `User`.
5. To access an `Entities` object, your `UserRepository` should have an object injected into it which creates `Entities` objects on a one-per-request basis. Let's call the interface for this object an `IPerRequestEntitiesFactory`, which you can implement with an `HttpContextPerRequestEntitiesFactory` which creates and stores `Entities` objects in the `HttpContext.Items` collection. The factory would have a `GetEntities()` method on it, which would create an `Entities` object and store it in `HttpContext.Items` if one doesn't already exist.

There's other issues to consider (your `Entities` object should be disposed at the end of a request), but that's a reasonable structure to get you started.